# Debugging Backbone apps - seeing view name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For debugging purposes, I would like to see the name of the class of a Backbone view like so:

```
 var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

            className:'IndexView',
```

however, it doesn't seem like className is the right property for me to set.

When I run:

```
var view = new IndexView();
```

when I debug, className doesn't show up as a property of view...should I be using a different property other than className for this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to see the className of the view would be to do the following:

```
var view = new IndexView();
//print view class
console.log(view.className);
```